# Redirecting New Domain Name to Server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns, virtualhost

I recently purchased a new domain name from 1and1.com and used their HTTP redirect option to point to the address of my server. Let's say, for example, the fresh domain is **new.com** and the established server is **old.com**.

I have it redirecting to **old.com/new** via 1and1's configuration page, which works, save for the fact that when I visit **new.com**, it changes the browser's URL to **old.com/new**. This is obviously not what I want to happen.

I've set up htaccess rules:

```
# BEGIN New.com
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new.com
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://old.com/new [P] 
</IfModule>
# END New.com
```

Likewise, I've done the Apache configuration of Virtual Hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.new.com
  DocumentRoot /www/old/html/new/
</VirtualHost>
```

I then proceeded to flush my local DNS cache. Yet still, it persists in changing the address bar in my browser to **old.com/new**. What am I missing? Does it just need time to propagate or have I misconfigured / failed to properly set something up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the 1and1's "new.com" DNS entry to point to the same IP that "old.com" is using. While the htaccess rule (which I assume is at the new.com document root) kind of does what you want, it requires the mod_proxy be loaded, which is something I doubt 1and1 hosting allows.

What you need to do is set it up such that when you go to a site like [this](http://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx) and do a DNS lookup for `new.com`, you get the same IP as when you lookup "old.com".

On old.com's server, you have the vhost setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.new.com
  DocumentRoot /www/old/html/new/
</VirtualHost>
```

which should be all you need to at least access the contents in `/www/old/html/new/`.

Comment: I assume you mean that the DNS servers should be the same, and not that the DNS entry should point to the server IP of "old.com", correct?